# Python's Magic Method for representation of class?

Tags: python, magic-methods

I have a custom class like:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
    
    def get_name(self):
         return self.__name
```

What I want to do is to write

```
test = foo("test")
print test
```

instead of

```
test = foo("test")
print test.get_name()
```

What is the magic method for doing this?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python). Also, your posted code seems faulty (``foo().get_name()``).

Comment: I'm not sure why this is attracting "unclear what you're asking" votes: the question is perfectly clear.   Python has at least one method (actually two), which is called when a string representation of the class is needed, and the OP knows that one exists, but not its name.

Comment: @AmiTavory good pointer to `str` vs `repr`, but I'm not sure what is wrong with the OP's code.   Parens are only needed for print statements in python3.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Thanks. I was referring to the need for parens after ``foo``. In the OP's code, ``foo`` is a class.

Comment: Hah!   The actual typo is that it should be `print test.get_name()`.   No parens, and no foo :)    `foo()` in particular is not meaningful in this context (`foo` is a class, not a function).

Comment: Yup, you're right - that's the actual typo, probably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two methods that are relevant. There is the `__str__` method which "converts" your object into a string. Then there is a `__repr__` method which converts your object into a "programmer representation." The `print` function (or statement if you're using Python 2), uses the `str` function to convert the object into a string and then writes that to `sys.stdout`. `str` gets the string representation by first checking for the `__str__` method and if it fails, it then checks the `__repr__` method. You can implement them based on your convenience to get what you want.

In your own case, implementing a

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.__name
```

should be enough.

Comment: thanks for this full explanation. If I understood you correctly, this means, that the `__str__` method will only be used if a function(like `print`) need the string representation of this class. So, in my example, it is no problem if I write `f = foo('test'); i = foo('i'); i = f;` than `i` is a `f` and not only the name of `i` changed?!

Comment: After your series of statements, `i` and `f` point to the same object (In this case `foo('test')`). The `foo('i')` object is now not referenced by anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `__str__`

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_name()

f = foo("My name")

print f
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `__str__()` method like this:

```
class b:
     def __str__(self)
             return "hello"

n = b()

print n
hello
```