# Not able to print value of object

Tags: python, object

```
class Freelencer:
    company="google"
    level=0
    def upgradelevel(self):
        self.level=self.level+1
    
class Employee:
    company="visa"
    ecode=120
    
class Programmer(Freelencer,Employee):
    name="rohit"
    
p=Programmer()
p.upgradelevel()
print(p)
```

I want to print value of level is changed to 1. Below is the workflow of the code.
[image]

Comment: It would be better and easier for the community to answer your question if you ask in a more clear way and also format your code in a readable way.

Comment: Done please check now

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318638/pythons-magic-method-for-representation-of-class

Answer (score 1):

you are printing the object. you need to point "self.level".

> print(p.level)

Comment: Thanks mate the program is working fine now and i got the value in print i.e one

Answer (score 1):

In either the `Freelencer` or `Programmer` class, you need to define a `__str__` method that returns the string that should be shown when you `print()` the object. You could write a method as simple as this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'level ' + str(self.level)
```

Then `print(p)` will show

```
level 1
```

Comment: i done writing the function you provided but now it shows Programmer is not defined

Comment: If `Programmer` is not defined, you probably didn't run all the code you showed. Try running your whole code block, with a `__str__` method added to one of those classes. Then it should work OK.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to override the print method in the Programmer class. use

```
def __repr__(self):
print(self.name) # or whatever you want to print
```

Comment: why i am not able to print the object value just with print method ? it gives me location of object in o/p i.e <__main__.Programmer object at 0x000002A00130BBB0>